# Binary to Graph

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an int array like the following

```
[1 0 0 0 1]  
[1 1 0 0 1]  
[1 1 0 0 1]
```

It's not moredimensional. I wrote this in more than one line only for better formatting.
I'm now going to find a method how to convert this array to a graph.

I found these steps of algorithm

1. Expand the image to α x 
   α pixel size
2. Thin the image to unit 
   thickness using any 
   thinning algorithm
3. Walk through every line 
   drawn to identify points of 
   intersection, lines/curves 
   connecting these points
4. During the walk, if the 
   edge is found, regard its 
   end-point as separate 
   point
5. Note the starting point, ending 
   point, point of max dist from 
   start and shape (line/curve) for 
   figures that connect 2 points.
6. If the length of any 
   line/curve is < β 
   then delete it

But I don't know how to implement it.
Has someone an idea?
Step 2 i already did.

Here is more information of the algorithm:

Here a graph represents the vertices and the edges. The 
edges are the lines or curves connecting any 2 points. 
Every point where an edge ends/starts is regarded as a 
vertex. We are also interested in knowing the point for 
every line/curve, which is at the maximum distance from 
the start point. This is useful when the graph may contain 
a closed curve E.g. O would be regarded as a curve from a 
vertex that ends at the same vertex.

Each edge must hence represent the start vertex, end 
vertex, shape (line/curve) and the point of maximum 
separation from start vertex. The image expansion is done 
by calculating the expansion factor (final image size/initial 
image size), for both the x and y coordinates. The start and 
end coordinate of each pixel in the new image are then 
measured by multiplying with the expansion factor. The 
lines and curves are differentiated from the maximum and 
minimum angle subtended by the start of the line/curve, a 
point situated γ units further from the start and all points 
2γ units from the start (Refer Fig.3). For a line the 
difference between the maximum and minimum angle

Source: http://ijcsi.org/papers/7-2-1-16-25.pdf

Is this going into the right direction?

```
// Create the graph
Graph<short> graph = new Graph<short>();
// Step to the array ([1 0 0 1 0] [1 1 0 0 1] ...)
for (int i = 0; i < marked.Length; i ++)
{
    if (marked[i] == true) //if the value is 1
    {
        // Create a new Node (with 1 as value)
        GraphNode<short> node = new GraphNode<short>(1);
        // And for all sorounding pixels with the value 1
        for (int count = 0; count < getSurroundedPixel; count++)
        {   
            // Create a new Node
            GraphNode<short> surrondNode = new GraphNode<short>(1);
            // And add the edge between the two nodes to the graph (costs = 1)
            graph.AddDirectedEdge(node, surrondNode, 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I still find it difficult to tell what the authors regard as a vertex. Only the extremal and intersection points? Every point on the way? Anyway, I would start by using every point on the way and then cleaning things up (based on the angle of consecutive edges). Keep in mind that the error accumulates over time.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think a vertex is each point on the way.  How would you "start by using every point on the way and then cleaning things up"?

Comment: Then you just need to insantiate a vertex for each filled pixel and add edges for filled neighbours.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I understood it like something like that:  Oh the code is too long for the comment.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I've edited my startpost with my trying of code.

Comment: Looks good. The edge should probably be undirected. Furthermore, only add edges to marked neighbours.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you! I got it now. Should it bei right now?  In the article it is said "and the point of maximum 
separation from start vertex" and something with degress. Do you know how to implement that? (Schön dass du ein Deutscher bist und wir auf Englisch schreiben) Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Well, that's something the paper did not mention. It seems that an edge is not just an edge, but a geometric primitive (curve or straight line). They differentiate between line and curve with the angle deviation (min and max) in a specific surrounding. Maximum separation means maximum distance from the start vertex in this case. Sorry I can't be of more help. Maybe you find some code the authors published.